# Attempt or try? Which word

Tags: word-usage

How can I explain to ESL pupils what the difference is between "an attempt" and "a try" (as nouns).

For example: Why can I say "I passed first try", but not *"this is a try to create a perfect human"?

Comment: +1, Wow, this is a good one! I gotta remember this, the noun use of "try" vs "attempt". It might come in handy in catching foreign spies! :D

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, "Try" is usually for something a little simple. But "Attempt" shows a little complexity or increase in difficulty level of whatever is being attempted.

Comment: It was a good *try*. I mean your *attempt* was good! :)

Comment: @MaulikV - Actually, I think there's some truth to this answer. A better way to say it might be that "try" is more commonly used in informal speech, while "attempt" has a more formal ring to it.

Answer (score 1):

You asked **as a noun**. Don't bother then! They both work quite similarly.

> I passed my exams on/at my very first try *(sentence reconstructed; thanks Erik Kowal)*

And why not, you can certainly use *try* that way...

> This is merely a *try* to create something *(sentence reconstructed)*

Refer Cambridge Dictionary for the **noun** 'try'

> [try = attempt](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/try)

However, I'd still see the *context* and choose my word.

For instance, I'd prefer *attempt* over try here...

> He made no *attempt* to be amicable.

Comment: Yes. Essentially, the distributions of 'attempt' and 'try' are somewhat idiosnycratic. 'Have a go / stab!' ; 'Have a try!' ; '*Have an attempt!' // 'His attempt was over within two weeks.' ?/*'His try was over within two weeks.' // 'His attempt to reach the mountain was pathetic.' / '*His try to reach the mountain was pathetic.'

Comment: To read idiomatically to a native speaker of British or American English, "I passed my exams in a very first try" is better rendered as "I passed my exams **on/at my** very first try".

Comment: @ErikKowal I fully agree. It sounds far better. Thanks. A thing learned. Won't forget this! :)

Comment: @MaulikV - Glad to be of assistance.  :)

Comment: I've made an attempt at looking up another entry, **[attempt](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/attempt)**. It doesn't say "try = attempt". In B2, it says that *attempt (n.) is "the act of trying to do something, **especially something difficult"***.

Comment: @DamkerngT. But then the same dictionary uses both! *They closed the road in an attempt **(= to try to)** to reduce traffic in the city.*. That's why I wrote 'quite similar...' in my answer. However, I also said that in some context, one word will be preferred over another.